# Change value of 9 buttons when called/invoked one function

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

There are 9 buttons in my page calling the same js function, I want to change the value of buttons which called the function to "abc". How can I do it?! Please help me.
I know I can use 9 different functions individually for 9 buttons, but that would be too lengthy.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow it is a basic requirement to show some basic code of your attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function by clicking on your button an `event` happens. This `event` contains useful information including the element that triggered it. So you can modify your function like this and you'll achieve your result!

```
function changeIt(event) { 
     event.target.innerText = "abc";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found out one more solution, I passed element name as function parameter.    For example: <button name="b1" onclick="functi(this.form.b1);">Button</button>.      And similarly with all buttons.   Thanks again your solution is more appropriate.